# How I can monitor status of my custom application in Cloudera Manager?

Tags: monitoring, apache-kafka, cloudera-manager

I have my own custom application. It works with Apache Kafka and has two main parts: Producer and Consumer.

Is there a possibility to monitoring all running producers and consumers in Cloudera Manager (like a DataNodes of HDFS)? First and main feature that I need is showing of status of every instance (started or stopped).

Or maybe there are some another soft (except Cloudera Manager) to perform my request?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can/should be using an APM tool. The company I work for is AppDynamics, we provide deep transaction tracing and monitoring among other things for these types of apps. There are other leading tools in APM as well for example Dynatrace and New Relic.